# Simulate mousing away or page click to reset hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a purely CSS-based tooltip that appears on hover (`mouseenter`) and disappears on `mouseout`/`mouseleave`; on click, it runs some code that happens to keep the user on the same page. However, on mobile, the `mouseenter` and click parts run at the same time, which leaves me with a visible tooltip that doesn't disappear until you tap somewhere else on the page since there's no natural `mouseout`/`mouseleave`.

To improve the UX, I tried to simulate the `mouseout`/`mouseleave` event on the clicked element after 1.5s (using `setTimeout()`), which doesn't work:

```
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
  // Other stuff

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).trigger('mouseleave');
  }, 1500);
});
```

and

```
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
  // Other stuff

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).mouseleave();
  }, 1500);
});
```

I've also tried using a specific element selector instead of `$(this)`, which didn't work either.

Now, I'm trying to simulate a page click to reset the hover event using:

```
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
  // Other stuff

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('body, html, #main').trigger('click');
  }, 1500);
});
```

If I trigger the click on a different element such as my hamburger menu, the trigger works. And if I manually tap somewhere else on the page, it resets the tooltip hover and hides it, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm trying to just simulate what would happen on the `mouseout` event or page click as opposed to trying to target touch devices since the rest of the behaviour is fine for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you create a new function (the one inside the setTimeout), it also changes the context of "this". You need to extract the value of this before it's context is changed.

You could try setting this to a variable before you try referencing it inside the timeout

```
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
  var element = this;
  // Other stuff

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(element).trigger('mouseleave');
  }, 1500);
});
```

or use an arrow function in the timeout, which doesn't change the context of this (but this might have browser compatibility issues):

```
$('.my-element').on('click', function() {
  // Other stuff

  setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).trigger('mouseleave');
  }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried using a specific selector based on the data attribute, which didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your tooltip looks not so purely CSS if it depends on javascript events.
I'd suggest making your tooltip using `:hover` CSS selector - then it will work on **mouse** over only.

```css
.tooltipped{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip {
 position:absolute;
 left:100%;
 padding:2px;
 margin-left:2px;
 border:1px solid gray;
 background: #FFFF99;
 font-size:12px;
 opacity:0;
 transition: opacity 0.3s;
 
 }

 @media(hover: hover) {
  .has-tooltip:hover + .tooltip {
   opacity:1;
   transition: opacity 0.3s 0.3s;
  }
 }

 @keyframes touch-tooltip {
 from {
    opacity: 0;
 }
 10% {
    opacity: 1;
 }
 90% {
    opacity: 1;
}
to {
   opacity: 0;
}
}
@media(hover: none) {
 .has-tooltip:hover + .tooltip {
   transition: none;
   animation-duration: 2s;
   animation-name: touch-tooltip;
 }
 }
```

```html
<div class="tooltipped">
<button class='has-tooltip'>Hello</button>
<span class='tooltip'>world</span>
</div>
```

P.S. I used also `:focus` selector to prevent showing tooltip on tap.

P.P.S I removed :focus selector because it disable tooltips after first click on button. Instead I used media query to disable tooltips on touch screens.

P.P.P.S hover+transition for mouse and hover+animation for touch

Comment: It's pure CSS in its primary function, but I'm having to use JS to enhance it for mobile. This is what I'm using: https://chrisbracco.com/a-simple-css-tooltip, which uses `:hover`. I'll try playing with your suggestion.

Comment: I just found in my solution tooltip will never appear again once the button was clicked already and still has a focus.
And about js solution - you can try to do [blur()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/blur) on the element

Comment: I tried `blur()` too, but I checked and apparently, it's not in focus after clicking.

Comment: I removed :focus selector. Instead I used media query to disable tooltips on touch screens. Take a look plz.

Comment: Will this still show the tooltip by tapping on touchscreens?

Comment: No, I intentionally disabled tooltip on tap. Do you need it for a touch screen? I thought you are fighting wit it.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that most of the functionality is fine on touch and non-touch screens. The only issue on touchscreens is that once the element is tapped and the tooltip is shown, it stays shown and doesn't hide like it would on desktop when the mouse moves away.  You can see an example here by clicking/tapping the link icon next to each question: http://foreverboosted.co/faq.html.

Comment: so you want it to disappear on mouseout or by timeout in case of touch screen? 
well it's doable with css I think, let me try.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to simulate the mouseout event (after a 1.5-second delay) on touchscreens

Comment: Ok, try this. On touch it will show tooltip and then fade it after some time (animation-duration: 2s)
But to see it again user will need to tap away before tapping on it again.